# Max dimension for Bayesian Optimization (GPyOpt, GPFlow)

Tags: python, machine-learning, optimization

Does anybody know how quickly the Bayesian Optimization algorithm slows down as a function of the dimension of the search space?  What is a good estimate of the maximum dimension that one can reasonably use?  I am thinking especially of GPyOpt and GPFlowOpt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a general rule of thumb, Bayesian optimisation becomes ineffective when the dimension of the search space is > 15. This will obviously depend on volume and utility function landscape. Check https://arxiv.org/abs/1902.10675 for an example of bayesian optimisation coupled with some reversible dimensional reduction (an auto-encoder there).